# Python ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas

I saw stack over flow post about this but nothing is matching with my requirement, So I'm creating this post. I'm using python 3.6. I have a data frame df_student.The sample data looks like following figure
[image]

I'm trying to filter the data frame using following code

```
df_filter1=df_student.loc[(df_student['year'] == x & (df_student['Grade']==y) & (df_student['Mail']==z)]
```

x,y & z are generating from code,sorry I won't be able to share the code. But after running this I got error message

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

After inspecting, I found x,y,z  are generated as a single value'Series' object  .x,y & z are str type also in my data frame year as int64 type, Grade & mail are 'O' type. So I modified the code & used following code

```
df_filter1=df_student.loc[(df_student['year'] == int(x.values[0]) & (df_student['Grade']==y.values[0]) & (df_student['Mail']==z.values[0])]
```

Now, I'm not getting any error message but df_filter1 is showing as an empty data frame where it should have some rows.Kindly suggest me what modification I need to do

I have done following modification as per 
jezrael's suggestion

```
df_filter1=df_student.loc[(df_student['year'] == x.astype(int).iat[0]) & 
                          (df_student['Grade']==y.iat[0]) & 
                          (df_student['Mail']==z.iat[0])]
```

But getting error message as

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

I have modified code as per  jezrael's  suggestion & reloaded the data from my csv file again & got these errors in my next run

```
  File "<ipython-input-69-6c2be16ee93f>", line 6, in studQuery
    df_filter1=df_student.loc[(df_student['year'] == x) & (df_student['Grade']==y.iat[0]) & (df_student['Mail']==z.iat[0])]

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1964, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1971, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1645, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3590, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2444, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1210, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'year'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if-else statement for check if type of value is `int`:

```
x = int(x) if isinstance(x, int) else int(x.iat[0])
df_filter1=df_student.loc[(df_student['year'] == x) & 
                          (df_student['Grade']==y.iat[0]) & 
                          (df_student['Mail']==z.iat[0])]
```

Comment: Hey, you should refrain from answering typos. Alternate solutions can be mentioned in the comments. Instead, vote to close.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - you are rigth, but I test it and problem is with something else, because if remove `)` then get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Hi @jezrael.It is working for one set of x,y & z & for another set, I'm getting error message as AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'iat'.Kindly suggest

Comment: oops, typo Then need `x.astype(int).iat[0]` or `int(x.iat[0])`

Comment: Ho @jezrael, I have done modification as per your first option.But getting error message as AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'astype'.I have updated the modified code in my first thread. Can you please look & suggest? My guess is for some cases x is not stored as series object instead it is storing as simple integer variable.It's a big for loop code so it's difficult to verify my guess.

Comment: OK, what is `type(x)` ?

Comment: It's a big for loop & it's happening in some value in middle of for loop. I will try to find.

Comment: It's <class 'int'>

Comment: Hmmm, hard to know without data. so are data confidental?

Comment: Yes, it's client data. Is there any generalized method that can applicable for series as well as integer?

Comment: So,is possible use `x = x.astype(int)` and then `df_filter1=df_student.loc[(df_student['year'] == x.iat[0]) & 
                          (df_student['Grade']==y.iat[0]) & 
                          (df_student['Mail']==z.iat[0])]` ?

Comment: And another improvement, `x,y,z` are columns in one DataFrame? And need loop each row in this df, generate `x,y,z` and compare?

Comment: @jezrael,I'm getting AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'astype' for your code & my dataframe size is too big it has 21,749,815 rows.So for loop is time expensive

Comment: Is there any way that I will check if my data type is series then I will use it with iat & if it is int then I will use the variable only?

Comment: Hi @jezrael,sorry to disturb you again. After my first successful run,I have reloaded the data from my csv file again using the command pd.read_csv('student.csv') ,it's the same data which I used previously, then run the code & again got a long list of error message which I have added in my first post. Only thing I saw is that now year field is with data type int32. I also tried to convert it using `df_student['year']=df_student['year'].astype(np.int64)` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Not easy answer without your code and sample data. So I get idea - is possible send me to my email in my profile your anonymize data csv with your code? 10 rows is nice. Thanks.